# How to effectively use the 'application.js' file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would to effectively use the `application.js` file by stating in it some JavaScript functions shared between my application. For instance, I would like to attach `data-*` attributes to my HTML tag (as made [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)) and use those functions "the Rails way". However, since I am new to JavaScript, I do not know how to state functions in the `application.js` file and how to call those from within view templates.

There are some guides on the web where I can learn more about?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: @Michal Szyndel - I am asking for online resources as examples and tutorials on the matter of using `data-*` attributes and similar JavaScript practices "the Rails way".

Comment: @Backo That's specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow. You cannot ask for people to recommend their favourite off-site resources (such as tutorials) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should only rely on the edge guides if you're using edge Rails (pre-release), because they might document features not present in the generally available package.
[This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) is the same guide for the current Rails version.

Then, to answer your question:

The use of `data-*` attributes on HTML elements is not a Rails technique, and in fact it isn't related to any specific framework.
While it is true that your back-end (in this case, Rails) will need to decide what to write in those `data-*` attributes *when it generates the HTML response*, using them with javascript is something that happens on the front-end, and it's definitely not related to Rails.

In any case, if you are a complete beginner the guide you're reading (ajax and unobstrusive javascript) will only confuse you.

You should start with some [Javascript tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) and read about [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to understand the role of `application.js` in Rails.